# Broken CXX compiler error on cmake when building aws-sdk-cpp for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, macos, amazon-web-services, static-libraries

I want to build static aws libs core, s3 and transfer for iOS which i downloaded from this [link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp). I am using macOS **High Sierra 10.13.6** and **Xcode 10.0**.

I am trying  to run cmake on the source from the link with this command:

```
cmake ../aws-sdk-cpp 
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang 
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-mios-version-min=11" 
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ 
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-mios-version-min=11" 
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release 
-DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk 
-DFORCE_CURL=ON 
-DENABLE_OPENSSL_ENCRYPTION=OFF 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/user/Desktop/script/lib/ios/arm64/aws-sdk-cpp 
-DCPP_STANDARD=14 
-DSIMPLE_INSTALL=ON 
-DENABLE_TESTING=OFF 
-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64 
-DBUILD_ONLY="core;s3;transfer" 
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
```

But I get error about **broken compiler CXX**:

> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
>   -- broken
>
> CMake Error at
>   /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.3/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45
>   (message):   The C++ compiler
>
> ```
> "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++"
> ```
>
> is not able to compile a simple test program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> ```
> Change Dir: /Users/user/Desktop/script/lib/ios/build/aws-sdk-cpp-iPhoneOS/aws-sdk-cpp/build/.deps/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> ```

I have seen similar problems on this topic but I could not find any solution. Thanks in advance.

Current version is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ --version

Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to re-install the Xcode CLT and see if that fixes it first. If it still doesn't work, you may have to homebrew install either gcc or llvm and use one of them as your compiler to see if that fixes it.

Comment: @sweenish thank you for reply. I will try as you suggested.

Comment: after trying the above the problem is still not solved. If i found solution to this i will post update here. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After downloading the aws source, try with older version like:

```
git checkout 1.7.9
```